# laravel + vue js API store function doesn't work on shared hosting but works well on localhost

Tags: laravel, vue.js

All cruds work well both on shared hosting and localhost except create (store).

here is my `addtoqueue` controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $last = antri::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->latest()->first();

   if ( $last ) {
       $tambah =  $last->number + 1;
   }
   else {
       $tambah =  1;
   }
    
   $newantri = new antri;
   $newantri->user_id = $request->user_id;
   $newantri->number = $tambah;
   $newantri->called = 0;

   $newantri->save();
   return $newantri;
}
```

`model`:

```
class antri extends Model
{
   use HasFactory;
}
```

`api route` :

```
Route::post('queue', [addtoqueue::class, 'store']);
```

the trigger:

```
<v-btn elevation="2" v-on:click="increase" >Ambil Nomor Antrian</v-btn>
```

the script:

```
methods: {
increase: function() {
    axios.post('/api/queue/', {
       user_id: this.user.id
    })
.  then( response=> {
     if( response.status == 200 ) {
      this.$emit('itemchanged');
     }
   })
.  catch( error => {
     console.log(error);
   })
  window.location.reload();      
}
```

tested using `postman` worked well too on both local and share hosting database.
can anyone figure out what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. I got `Status Code 301 moved permanently` every time `post method` is requested. this caused the `url` structure changed from `domain/api/target` to `domain/public/api/target`and of course it won't hit the `store` function in the controller.
I edited `.htaccess` file in `public` folder from:
`RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]`
to
`RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=307]`

which means from permanently moved to temporarily redirected.

and this solved my problem.